# Ada type conflict in array indices

Tags: arrays, types, ada

This is the code and the algorithm works in Java but in Ada it still raises the CONSTRAINT_ERROR. In Ada we start indexing the array at 1 and not at 0 as in most other languages. For some reason I am still indexing out of array.

```
 procedure spiral is

   M : Matrix := ((11,22,33,44,55),(1,8,3,8,9),(10,10,20,30,1));

   lastcol, firstcol, lastrow : Integer := 1;
   rowsize, colsize : Integer := 0;

   procedure Print ( M: in Matrix ) is
   begin

  rowsize := M'Length(1);
  colsize := M'Length(2);

  while lastrow<=rowsize loop

        for I in Index range Index(firstcol)..Index(colsize) loop
           Put( Elem'Image(M(Index(lastrow),Index(I))));
           Put( Ascii.HT );
        end loop;

        lastrow := lastrow + 1;

        if (lastrow>=rowsize) then 
           return;
        end if;

        for J in Index range Index(lastrow)..Index(rowsize) loop
           Put( Elem'Image(M(Index(J),Index(colsize))));
           Put( Ascii.HT );
        end loop;

        colsize := colsize - 1;


        for I in reverse Index range Index(colsize)..Index(lastcol) loop
           Put( Elem'Image(M(Index(rowsize), Index(I))));
           Put( Ascii.HT );
        end loop;

        rowsize := rowsize- 1;
        lastcol := lastcol+ 1;

        for I in reverse Index range Index(rowsize)..Index(lastrow) loop
           Put( Elem'Image(M(Index(I), Index(firstcol))));
           Put( Ascii.HT );
        end loop;

        firstcol := firstcol + 1;

     end loop;
   end Print;

begin
   --Put(rowDown);
   Print(M);
end spiral;
```

the Matrix package is defined as:

```
package Matrix_pack is

    type Index is new Integer;
    type Elem is new Integer;
    type Matrix is array (Index range <>, Index range <>) of Elem;

end Matrix_pack;
```

Comment: Why not make colLeft etc Indexes? Cleaner than needless type conversions like `M(Index(rowUp),Index(I))` to index the array.

Comment: Because then I can not do operations on them.

Comment: Also when doing the `M(Index(rowUp),Index(I))` I get a CONSTRAINT_ERROR: index check failed

Comment: ??? Literals and all the usual operators should work on your new integer types. What you can't do is mix them with other integer types without conversion - which is the point of making them a new type. (Otherwise you'd use a subtype). So, what really doesn't work? ...  If you get that CONSTRAINT_ERROR you were trying to index outside the array. Make an MCVE that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: It seems from your comment above that you have got your program at least to compile and you are now asking a different question. Could you perhaps update your question to reflect this new situation?

Comment: I updated the code but, still the same CONSTRAINT_ERROR.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. - It is *at least* missing the declaration of the type `Matrix`.

Comment: "In Ada we start indexing the array at 1 and not at 0 as in most other languages" ... WRONG! In Ada we start the array at the most sensible index for the problem domain, because we're not forced to start at 0. Sometimes 0 is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be done in two steps:

- First: Make the indexing type used in the loop explicit:

```
for I in Index range colLeft .. colRight loop
   Put (Elem'Image (M (rowUp, I)));
end loop;
```

- Second: Fix the declarations of `colLeft` and `colRight`:

```
colLeft, colRight : Index;
```